# Supervisor and reference, should they be different

Tags: applications, references

When a company asks for supervisor and reference should they be different?

I'm filling out a job application and in the "Previous Employment" section, the application asked for my supervisors' phone numbers. But in the "References" section it asks for references, do I put in the same people, or find more references?

Comment: Ask the company. Some want them to be different, others don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have other references, if possible. In some cases, that could be the superior's superior (e.g., someone who can speak to your work ethic and character but did not manage you day-to-day), a college or grad/professional school professor, other professionals who have done business with you, etc.

If you can't expand like that, I would suggest (*if possible*) that you put contact info for HR under each position on that part of the application and then list your supervisors under References.